# Barycentric Subdivision of a singular 2-simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Chapter 3 Section 6(Page 40) in Dold's book Lectures on Algebraic Topology [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/dold4.pdf), the author gives the definition of barycentric subdivision, it is constructed as coning the barycenter of a singular simplex with the barycentric subdivision of its boundary.

I tried to draw the picture for the singular 2-simplex, but didn't get the picture I'm supposed to get. As in the picture, I calculated the barycentric subdivision of a 2-simplex, and tried to draw $B_2\cdot\beta_1(\iota_2\varepsilon_2^0)$. Since $B_2\cdot$ is the cone operation so I just connect $B_2$ with $e_2$ and $e_1$. Instead of getting two complexes $[B_2, B_1, e_2]$ and $[B_2, B_1, e_1]$(which I'm supposed to get), I only get one complex $[B_2, e_1, e_2]$.

[image: barycentric subdividion of sigma_2]

So could someone give some comments on my calculation and explain which operation requires me to connect $B_2$ to $B_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's calculate $\beta_1(\iota_2 \epsilon_2^0)$. We have

\begin{align*}
\beta_1(\iota_2  \epsilon_2^0)
& = \iota_2 \epsilon_2^0 \beta_1(\iota_1) \\
& = \iota_2 \epsilon_2^0(B_1 \beta_0 \partial \iota_1) \\
& = \iota_2 \epsilon_2^0(B_1(\iota_1 \epsilon_1^0 - \iota_1 \epsilon_1^1)) \\
& = \iota_2 \epsilon_2^0(B_1([e_1] - [e_0])) \\
& = \iota_2 \epsilon_2^0([B_1, e_1] - [B_1, e_0]).
\end{align*}
I might have made some mistakes as I'm not familiar with Dold's notations, but the reason that you get two simplizes is that the barycentric subdivision $\beta_1(\iota_1)$ is the coned boundary of $\iota_1$, which is a chain consisting of two simplices.